# How to understand this stress mark

Tags: pronunciation, stress

Duden [gives](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wogen) the following transciption for *wogen*: [voˈɡn̩]. I don't know what to make of it. Before seeing the transription I assumed that *e* would be silent, and *o* would be stressed as the only vowel left. *e* is indeed absent, but what is the stress mark applied to? I must assume *n̩*, but I have a very hard time imagining an *n*-like sound that's also a vowel enough to be stressed.

What does the transcription actually mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That transcription looks like a mistake to me. »wogen« is definitely stressed on the first syllable, on »o«. They do get this right before, when they underline the »o« in "Betonung". For what it's worth, Wiktionary gives the transcription [ˈvoːɡn̩], which is also right in that the »o« is a long vowel.

Comment: Now I have to worry if _o_ is long or not. How reliable is Wiktionary in this regard?

Comment: @Michail I don't know about Wiktionary in general, but I can confirm that »o« is long (native speaker).